# Stroika: ObjectOrientedMapper and Multisets fails: mapper.AddCommonType<Containers::MultiSet<int>> ();

Tags: c++

AddCommonType does not currently support MultiSet (or SortedMultiSet) although it supports most of the Stroika container classes

ex:

```
`ObjectVariantMapper ovm;
ovm.AddCommonType<Containers::Set<String>> (); // works fine
ovm.AddCommonType<Containers::MultiSet<String>> (); // fails`
```

produces

> 'Stroika::Foundation::DataExchange::ObjectVariantMapper::MakeCommonSerializer_':
> none of the 6 overloads could convert all the argument
> types PS2 C:\work\PS2\ThirdPartyComponents\Stroika\StroikaRoot\Library\Sources\Stroika\Foundation\DataExchange\ObjectVariantMapper.inl

Answer (score 0):

This issue is tracked in the Stroika bug database https://stroika.atlassian.net/browse/STK-951

And it is fixed for Stroika v2.1.9 (https://github.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika/releases/tag/v2.1.9

The fix is for MultiMap<> to be supported with ObjectVariantMapper::AddCommonType ().

However, for container types that don't have builtin support in ObjectVariantMapper, if they are addable via Containers::Adapters::Adder, you can add a serializer with ObjectVariantMapper::MakeCommonSerializer_WithAdder().

For example, this is in the Stroika regression tests:

```cpp
    ObjectVariantMapper mapper;
    MultiSet<int>       s1;
    mapper.AddCommonType<CountedValue<int>> ();
    mapper.Add (ObjectVariantMapper::MakeCommonSerializer_WithAdder<MultiSet<int>> ());
    s1.Add (2);
    s1.Add (2);
    s1.Add (3);
    VariantValue  sAsVariant         = mapper.FromObject (s1);
    MultiSet<int> mappedBackToObject = mapper.ToObject<MultiSet<int>> (sAsVariant);
    VerifyTestResult (s1 == mappedBackToObject);
```